# Delayed installation of downloaded packages on another computer with CMake

Tags: cmake

Is it possible to delay the installation of downloaded packages on another computer with CMake?

I know it is possible to download and install a package with CMake (ExternalProjectAdd function) on the same computer. I would like to know if it is possible to download a package on a computer and install it on another one.

I need to do this to be able to download dependencies of a software on a personal computer (internet connexion, root privilege) and then move to a cluster (no internet connexion, no root privilege) to install the software and its dependencies.

EDIT: here is an example of my problem.

CMake is used to generate a code X. This code depends on a library Y available on the Internet. I want to generate X on a cluster with no Internet connexion and no root privilege. Therefore, I cannot download Y from this cluster (no Internet connexion) and I cannot install it from a package manager (no root privilege). I need to download Y from another computer (personal computer).

My question is "How could I download Y from a personal computer and then generate X on this cluster with CMake?".

Comment: "I would like to know if it is possible to download a package on a computer and install it on another one." - Do you mean building the *project* on the one computer, and *packaging* it. Then "unpack" that package on another computer? This is normal behavior for many projects. CMake has CPack, which may "pack" the project in many formats, which can be installed (unpacked) on other machine. It is not clear what do you want from CMake...

Comment: I use the term "package" as it is understood in the "find_package" function. However, you can replace "package" by "library" as well. I added a concrete description of my problem in the original message. Please tell me if it is not clear.

Comment: "How could I download Y from a personal computer and then generate X on this cluster with CMake?" - Without CMake, do you able to download something from the PC to the cluster? CMake is not a magic download tool, `ExternalProject_Add` just uses existing tools (e.g. git) for download things. It supports limited number of downloads ways, so it depends on your actual configuration, whether `ExternalProjectAdd` fits for you or not. You may also consult its [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/module/ExternalProject.html) for check possibilities of this command.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your answer. Maybe something is missing in the description of my problem but I cannot see what it is.